# How can I keep css rules of tags containing text the same before and after I put them inside <li> tag?

Tags: html

I've difficulties to set up css rules of tags containing text inside **li** tag. Anything inside **li** becomes anormaly smaller. To make it readable, I need to make it bigger in an important scale (for instance, from .8em to 1.1 em). Unfortunately, the new text's size doesn't always match the one before it was put inside the anchor tag.

What I want is to be able to restore the previous settings as before I place the tag containing the text inside the **li** tag. Is there a trick to do that? Let's say, for font-size = 12px, do I need to make it, for instance, 15px to go back to 12px?

**EDIT**

Actually, **a** tag is not causing me trouble, but it's rather **li tag** which shrinks all the  put inside. So, I've edited the above post by replacing all the **a tag** by **li tag**. I'm sorry for that. Anyway; while I thought I've run into an issue, after reading article suggested by S. Jones, I'm aware of the inheritence property on some tags.

Here's the issue. Let's say, I have

```
<a href = "somewhere">Somewhere<a>
a { font-size: 12px;}
```

After I put the above tag inside a **li tag**

```
<li><a href = "somewhere">Somewhere<a></li>
a { font-size: ???;}
```

After reading S. Jones article, I wonder if I need to disable inheritence or use IMPORTANT!!!

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you've got cascading and inheritance issues with your CSS.

You might want to look through the following:

- [Cascading Order and Inheritance in CSS](http://monc.se/kitchen/38/cascading-order-and-inheritance-in-css)
- [CSS Structure and Rules](http://htmlhelp.com/reference/css/structure.html)

---

There are several ways that you could fix your issue, but I can't say sure without seeing your CSS and HTML.  If you could post some sample HTML along with your CSS file which illustrates your issue - several people here on SO will be able to recommend solutions.

---

**Debug Recommendation:** If you're not currently using it, you might want to look at installing the [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) plugin for Firefox.  It's a great tool for inspecting your page.  You can highlight specific areas, and Firebug will show you which HTML elements and CSS classes are responsible for the layout.

---

**UPDATE:** Thanks, that's much more clear.  Check your CSS file for any styling being applied to your list elements (`li`, `ol`, `ul`). You'll either need to remove some styling from these elements, or define font-size specifically for `a` elements nested within `li`.

For Example: `li a {font-size:12px;}` which will set the font size for `a` elements, only when they are nested within `li` elements.

Cheers.

Comment: @S. Jones: The article has helped to see where lay the problem. However, that's still overwhelming for me. So, I've re-state my problem. Check out the edit above.

Comment: Thanks. But before I let you go, can you tell me if such tool exists for Google Chrome as well. Because, I like chrome much better than Firefox. Otherwise, I don't mind, I'll use the firebug you suggested.

Comment: @Richerd77 I've just edited my answer to demonstrate something that might fix it for you.  Let me know if it works out.

Comment: @Richard77 It looks like you can install "Firebug Lite" on Chrome. I've never tried it out, but for Firefox, Firebug is a must have.

Comment: Anyway, that's might be a new thread. I'll install firebug and see what will happen.